# Данный код не работает после его переноса на UWP, как это исправить?

Tags: api, uwp

```
    private async Task PostRequestAsync()
    {
           WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.exmo.com/v1/ticker/");
           request.Method = "POST"; // для отправки используется метод Post
                                    // данные для отправки
           string data = "";
           // преобразуем данные в массив байтов
           byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
           // устанавливаем тип содержимого - параметр ContentType
           request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           // Устанавливаем заголовок Content-Length запроса - свойство ContentLength
           request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

           //записываем данные в поток запроса
           using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
           {
               dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
           }

           WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
           using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
           {
               FilterJSON f = new FilterJSON();
               DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(f.GetType());
               var obj = (FilterJSON)jsonFormatter.ReadObject(stream);
               bitcoin = obj.BTC.buy_price;
               bitcoincash = obj.BCH.buy_price;
               ethereum = obj.ETH.buy_price;
               ethereumclassic = obj.ETС.buy_price;
               using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
               }
           }
           response.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `WebRequest`  возьмите `HttpClient` и вместо `FilterJSON`  возьмите `Json.Net`. А лучше просто возьмите `RestSharp Portable`, код сократится в разы и не придется со стримами ковыряться.